# Calculate trend of week

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

Lets say I have the statistics for the crimes that were committed this week in California:

On **Monday** there were **10** crimes committed.

**Tuesday: 6**

**Wednesday: 7**

**Thursday: 15**

And on **Friday: 8**

Now I want to calcualte the **Trend** of the week.
On wiki  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trend_estimation I saw different ways and formulas to calulate a trend! But I dont really know wich one I should use!

**How would you calculate a Trend?**

Thanks!!